# How to change Vuforia AnchorInputListenerBehaviour?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How to change Vuforia the `AnchorInputListenerBehaviour`, the original setting is clicked on the screen, I want to change it to judge the Micro Switch high or low signal?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't really understand your question.  What do you mean by `I want to change it to judge the Micro Switch high or low signal` .. how is this related to Vuforia? Could you please explain a bit more in detail what exactly your goal is?

Comment: vuforia itself is triggered by a screen click,
But I don’t want to be triggered by a screen click,
I want to trigger by clicking the 1/0 signal of the external button

Comment: Then why use something that is triggered by Vuforia at all? Simply use your own event?

Comment: The c script of vuforia cannot be edited, but I want to know its content so that I can modify the code

Comment: I am not familiar with unity,I use vuforia to create 3d objects and trigger special effects, so I need to trigger the special effects through an external button instead of clicking on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Vuforia code at all!

You seem to rather just want to have your own custom [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) in the Inspector you can invoke whenever you want to ;)

If you need it you can even extend this and add some parameters as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html) using [`UnityEvent<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) e.g. something like

```c#
[Serializable]
public class CustomEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CustomEvent _onButtonStateChanged;

    private bool lastState;

    // Now however you check your button states and get your pin data
    // on whatever condition you can simply invoke your event
    private void Update()
    {
        //TODO
        var currentState = GetYourButtonStateByMagic();
        
        if(currentState != lastState)
        {
            _onButtonStateChanged.Invoke(currentState);
            lastState = currentState;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to confirm his operation process, is vector2 the storage coordinate position? , When the screen is clicked, performhittest is triggered to place the square. My logic is like this